# Why do I keep getting 'It does not meet our quality standards'?

Tags: discussion

I tried to post a question and each time I try to submit it I get the error message

> It does not meet our quality standards.

This is my question :

> I have a Cent-Os 5.8 based VPS and its been like 4 months that i face
>   system hangs repeatedly.Each two or three other days i encounter a
>   server hang and i need to reset the VPS through my control panel where
>   i bought it( i cant access my vps internal panel when it hangs). Can
>   you please suggest me how i can start looking for the cause of these
>   hangs and eliminate it?

Why am I getting this message? What is wrong with my question?

Comment: I'm not sure if maybe this needs to be on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to get the attention of the developers? Not sure how often they look at all the SE site metas.

Comment: @derobert:Thank you,i had a bad experience couple of weeks ago because of not using meta!And now when i am using meta,No one is here to listen :-/ you,this is really sad and frustrating.I have a question to ask which is important to me, where else should i go and what else can i do about solving this issue?I would appreciate a hint or two if you will :)

Comment: I am not a SE developer so I can't say for sure, but I notices that you frequently do not put spaces between the end of your punctuation and the beginning of the next word. Also you are not capitalizing sentences or words like "I".

Comment: (I don't want to sound harsh on this, sorry if I do) I edited your question to improve readability; see this as an example on how spelling is important for a good question (and this might be triggering the 'low quality' filter).

Comment: @Renan:Thankyou,I'll have that in mind:)
Xenoterracide:Thank you too for pointing it out,I'll try my best to eliminate those mistakes as well.

Answer (score 11):

Try capitalizing your words and improving readability. I would do something like:

> I have a CentOS 5.8-based VPS and for 4 months I have been facing random system hangs every 2 or 3 days; then I need to reset the VPS through its control panel. How and where can I start debugging those hangs?

As you can see, it's much more readable and straight-to-the-point. If you still have the same problem after doing those improvements, then ask on Meta.SO, you might have found a bug or misbehaviour.